# Можно ли сделать произвольное окно модальным?

Tags: c#, windows, com

Например, есть компонент COM, который может создать нужно мне окно.

Однако, проблема в том, что окно создается не модальным, а среди методов нету никаких настроек.

Собственно вопрос, а можно ли произвольное окно имея его хендл сделать модальным?

Comment: интересно, как вы это себе представляете? Модальное окно полностью блокирует весь рабочий процесс до тех пор, пока не будет закрыто. Т.е. если вы открыли окно не блокируя основной процесс и потом простой манипуляцией с хендлом - заблокируете его? Странновато выглядит.

Comment: @Kromster, да..

Comment: Если еще подробнее, то класс MSDASC.DataLinksClass, который при вызове метода PromptEdit создает окно.

Comment: [Using Windows functions to make a window modal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5577265/2881286)